# Using React Paginate

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-redux

I am using React Paginate and just want the previous < and next level > on my page.but its showing the number from 1 to 10 too.Is there any way to get only level not the pagination numbers?.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: well with css u can do hide it with display none  and align back,next accordingly. But whats the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works:

```
<ReactPaginate previousLabel={"previous"} nextLabel={"next"} pageCount={0} ...anyOtherProps />
```

Otherwise you can just do some easy filtering. Some options are to target the page counts with CSS and adding the display:none attribute to it or simply removing it from the DOM with JS.

Comment: Great to hear! Please mark the answer if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the best component handling it, [react-pagination-custom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pagination-custom).

```
<TinyPagination
    total = {...}
    selectedPageId = {...}
    itemPerPage = {...}
    renderBtnNumber = {...}
    maxBtnNumbers = {...}
    preKey = '...'
    nextKey = '...'
    {...someOptionalProperties}
/>
```

It allow you custom everything (number buttons, wrap container, spread,..). Its document is well, demo is also clear.